# Same route different components after authorizing Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

Entry point (*sign in and sign out*) is available by `'/'` path (*component Entrypoint*). Authorized users are being redirected to the `'/home'` page (*component Home*).

Now I want to handle (only for authorized users) `'/'` path just as if it was `'/home'` path. It means if I would type `localhost:/` or `localhost:/home` there wouldn't be any difference or 404 page, router will redirect me to `'/'`. Also every non-common to router path will be handled as 404 (*component NotFoundComponent*).

But if I am unauthorized user, every workable path will redirect me to the entry point `'/'` (*component Entrypoint*).

How can I reach this with Vuejs/router?

Comment: Did you look at Vue Router's middleware documentation?

Comment: Why not just redirect to `/login` when the user is unauthorized?

Answer (score 0):

You can use beforeEach navigation guard of vue-router. ([Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html))

In you main.js(After initializing vue component) you need to write.

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // If user is authorized
  if isAuthorized() {
    if (to.path === '/') {
      next()
    } else if (to.path === '/path') {
      next('/')
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
      next('/')
  }
  next()
}
```

For every non-common routes you can add

`{path: '*', component: PageNotFound, name: 'PageNotFound'}`

in your routes.